# How to write regex expression for chinese character

Tags: java, selenium, pattern-matching

I need to know how we compile Chinese characters into the following words
`50,001 - 100,000` 積分

Eg: English wording:`50,001 - 100,000` points. This is written English wordings

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+\\s[A-Z]+)|(\\d+\\s(\\-|or)\\s(\\d|[a-z])+\\s"+Internationalization.getMessage("POINTS_RANGE_FILTER_POINTS")+")"
```

Comment: Replace `[A-Z]+` with `\\p{L}+`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBysFJ/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Looks good.:) ..Working for me.If incase is this for spanish and thai , how we can write it?

Comment: `\p{L}` supports any Unicode base letter. If you plan to match diacritics, too, use  `\p{L}\p{M}*+` instead. To match one or more, `(?:\p{L}\p{M}*+)+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `\p{L}` Unicode property class to match any Unicode letter. Also, your pattern needs a bit of adjustment to match the numbers in their entirety. See a fix below:

```
\d+(?:,\d{3})*\s*(?:(?:-|or)\s*\d+(?:,\d{3})*\s*)?\p{L}+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBysFJ/1)

In Java:

```
String rx = "\\d+(?:,\\d{3})*\\s*(?:(?:-|or)\\s*\\d+(?:,\\d{3})*\\s*)?\\p{L}+";
```

NOTE: If you do not care much about the regex precision (e.g. when just extracting these substrings), you may shorten the `\\d+(?:,\\d{3})*` to `\d[\d,]*`. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBysFJ/2).

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0+ consecutive sequences of `,` and 3 digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:(?:-|or)\s*\d+(?:,\d{3})*\s*)?` - 1 or 0 sequences (an optional one) that matches

  - `(?:-|or)` - a `-` or `or`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:,\d{3})*` - the number pattern as above
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\p{L}+` - 1+ Unicode letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as is. Java supports Unicode. Try this line

```
System.out.println("積分".matches(".分"));
```

It prints true